# How can i get the following results using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

Hi I have a table called `orders_pending`

it has columns `order_number` and `model`

```
order_number  | model

1                  1 
1                  2
2                  1
2                  3
2                  5
3                  5
4                  2
```

As you can see 1 order can have multiple models  , in my table no unique key , but if i take both the order number and model it is unique .

I want a result like this

```
order_number  | model

2                  1
2                  3
2                  5    
1                  1 
1                  2
```

Only `order_number's` that have more than one `model` and it should be sort according to the number of orders which are presented in the table

I tried lots of solutions but could not succeed  .

Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: try this: select * from 'tablename' where order_number='1'&&'2' ORDER BY model ASC

Comment: though i am not sure about syntax! check it on MySql docs... but logically you will get your output

Comment: @HardikAnavadia I have around 70,000 order numbers  so can not hard code ;)

Comment: ohh! i thought your problem is specific point oriented so!.... will get back you soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a subquery which gets the total number of models and filters out `order_number` which has multiple `models`. The result is then join with the table itself. Use the `TotalCount` column to order the result.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM orders_pending a
     INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT order_number, COUNT(*) TotalCount
        FROM  orders_pending
        GROUP BY order_number
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) b ON a.order_number = b.order_number
ORDER BY b.TotalCount DESC, a.order_number, a.model
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63606f/1)

Comment: hmmm , Thank you very much :), but seems it takes long time to excecute , i have over 70,000 records in the table , it is still executing :/

Comment: try adding index: `ALTER TABLE orders_pending ADD INDEX IDX_orders_pending (order_number, model)`

Comment: Oh  Great , i forgot that .  1.5764 sec lolz . Thank you very very much

Answer (score 1):

First we get the order_numbers which have more than one model.

```
SELECT order_number, COUNT(*) AS how_many_orders
FROM
orders_pending
GROUP BY order_number 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Then we join this to get every row in the table that belong to those order_numbers.

```
SELECT 
op.order_number, op.model
FROM 
orders_pending op
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT order_number, COUNT(*) AS how_many_orders
    FROM
    orders_pending
    GROUP BY order_number 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

) sq ON op.order_number = sq.order_number
ORDER BY how_many_orders, op.order_number
```